# How can i config Hyper-V in bios for dev windowsphone app

Tags: bios

I want to enable Hyper-V following [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). With my HP ProBook 4530S, when I log into BIOS i can't see feature, SLAT (Second Level Address Translation), Hardware-assisted virtualization, Data Execution Prevention (DEP) follow above this tutorial. Can any one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I know, its perfectly fine. Because it is a built in feature on HP ProBook 4530S. When you are asked "if you wanted to enter as a guest user", you can select "yes" or "no", this depends on the type of setting you want to change.

When you select yes, you will be taken to a boot setup with limited privileges. When you select no, you will be asked to login as an administrator where you will need to provide a username and password, this will take you to a boot setup with higher privileges.

Comment: @richie: thank for your reply. I'm trying both of them. Guest user and admin user, but i still figure out where can i config that feature

Comment: Got to BIOS and enabled the "**Parameter Virtualization Technology**", and then change **BIOS Security Settings** from **"View"** to **"Change for virtualization"**. Those are features which you need to change on BIOS.